# template overloading results in linker error / strange behaviour

Tags: c++, linker, language-lawyer, overloading, function-templates

with the following minimal example i get a linker error on my local system in visual studio 15.8.7 (standard console app with standard settings (just removed precompiled headers)): "Error LNK1179 invalid or corrupt file: duplicate COMDAT '??$f@H@@YAXH@Z'"

```
#include <cstdio>
template<typename T> void f(T) { printf("1"); }  //#1. T can be deduced
template<typename T> void f(int) { printf("2"); } // #2. T needs to be specified explicitly

int main()
{
    f(8); // a) calls #1
    f<int>(8); // b) calls #2           
}
```

- Commenting out either the call a) or call b) will result in successfully linking. Standalone call a) calls template definition #1. The second call b) calls template definition #2. As expected.
- Building in Release mode succeeds. Output is 11. So both calls call template definition #1. Unexpected. **ODR-violoation?**
- Additionally i observed the following strange behaviour (in debug settings):

  1. i comment out template definition #2
  2. i do a full rebuild
  3. i comment back in template definition #2
  4. i build (not rebuild, just build)
  5. build succeeds
  6. output is 11 instead of 12

**Incremental linking doing strange things?**

On wandbox, godbolt and coliru i can compile,link and run and get the expected behaviour with gcc and clang.

The observations described in bullet point 3 made me think it has to do with incremental linking. But maybe the code is also just not well defined? When studying https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template i encountered the following:

> Two expressions involving template parameters are called functionally
>   equivalent if they are not equivalent, but for any given set of
>   template arguments, the evaluation of the two expressions results in
>   the same value.

and

> If a program contains declarations of function templates that are
>   functionally equivalent but not equivalent, the program is ill-formed;
>   no diagnostic is required.

So, is the above code ill formed? Do i have an ODR-violation? Or is everything fine and its just a linker/compiler bug?

edit: fixed point 3. i comment back in definition #2 or course.

**Update:** New day, problems solved i guess. Today i can not reproduce the problem. I did not change anything on my system. I just booted up, opened my project and it worked like expected. Dont know whats going on. But its better this way compared to learn new special arcane template overloading rules :-P

Comment: i set up a complete new project with just the showed code in there.

Comment: Looks like ODR violation to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is fine. You have two *different* functions that are being invoked. This is a compiler and/or linker error.

[[temp.over.link]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.over.link) leads with:

> It is possible to overload function templates so that two different function template specializations have the same type.
>
> *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> // translation unit 1:
> template<class T>
>   void f(T*);
> void g(int* p) {
>   f(p); // calls f<int>(int*)
> }
>
> // translation unit 2:
> template<class T>
>   void f(T);
> void h(int* p) {
>   f(p); // calls f<int*>(int*)
> }
> ```
>
> *— end example ]*
>
> Such specializations are distinct functions and do not violate the one-definition rule.

You have two different function templates, full stop. The wording about equivalence has to do with template parameters and dependent expressions ([[temp.over.link]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.over.link#5)):

> Two expressions **involving template parameters** are considered equivalent if [...]

`int` does not involve a template parameter, so in no way can it be considered equivalent to `T`.

Comment: Sounds good. So it is no problem that both template functions in the end get instantiated to its final form of `void f(int)`? (in your given example the template parameter is the same, but not the function parameter. so i just want to be sure).

Comment: I think OP's `f` template functions are two overloads. Overloads of template functions is defined in `[temp.func.order]`.

Comment: @YSC I don't understand the point of the comment. Yes, they are two overloads. I say that in the answer?

Comment: @phön The function parameter is the same in the example - both calls invoke a function whose signature is `void(int*)`.

Comment: A piece is missing ^^. I was asking if you could explain how the compiler chose the right overload, I don't fill like `[temp.func.order]` explains it outside of _template argument deduction_.

Comment: @YSC Uh, you were not asking anything. But if you would actually like to ask something, you can actually do so directly.